# Protecting rows depending on specific (today) date

Tags: variables, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to code my Google Sheets to check ("scan") active sheet to find a date that is "today" - and then, depending on the day, protect all columns in that row (row in witch it found todays date), so that only owner can change it (protect from everyone else).

With the help of the forum i found some "solutions", but cant get to make it work. I think there is a problem with for loop (just prediction).

Script should check for today date, read how many colmuns are active and lock the row(s) with today + all previous dates. I'm still missing the protection to lock all the rows with ownership rights only and ofcourse to work :)

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('MY SHEET');

function lockRanges() {
  var dateRange = ss.getRange(2, 1, ss.getLastRow()-2, 1);
  var curDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "dd/M/YYYY");
  var val = dateRange.getDisplayValues();
  var row;
  var col;
  var end = ss.getLastRow();
  
  //Find last active column
  for (var y = 0; y <= ss.getLastColumn(); y++) {
    col = y + 1;
  }

  //Loop through all rows
  for(var x = 0; x <= end; x++){
    if(val[x][0]> curDate){
      row = x;
      break;
    }
  }

  var protection = ss.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE)
  if(protection.length > 0){
    var range = ss.getRange(2, 1, row, col);
    protection[0].setRange(range);
  }
  else{
    ss.getRange(2, 1, row, col).protect();
  }
}
```

Comment: Related question: [Apps Script to Build a Data Protection and only allow Spreadsheet Owner to edit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75051884/1330560).

Answer (score 0):

This script included the suggestions made in [Apps Script to Build a Data Protection and only allow Spreadsheet Owner to edit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75051884/1330560)

- add the owners email address on the last line of the script.

**Comments on the OP script.**

- `var dateRange = ss.getRange(2, 1, ss.getLastRow()-2, 1);`
  Since your range starts on row#2, the number of rows of data should be `ss.getLastRow()-1`.
  Insert `Logger.log("The date range is "+dateRange.getA1Notation())` to show the defined range .
- `var val = dateRange.getDisplayValues();`
  All "displayed" values are strings. In which case, you need to convert the current date to a string too with this line:
  `var curDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "dd/M/YYYY").toString()`
- `//Find last active column` - there's no need for a loop, just use
  `ss.getLastColumn()`
- `for (var y = 0; y <= ss.getLastColumn(); y++) {`
  `getLastColumn()` returns an index number but "y" is initialised at zero. So the number of times that the statement will run is `one more than the number of columns`.
  As noted above, this loop is unnecessary, BUT if it were used then it should read:
  `for (var y = 0; y < ss.getLastColumn(); y++) {`
- //Loop through all rows:  `for(var x = 0; x <= end; x++){`
  Since the first row in the range was #2  the number of rows of data is not `end = ss.getLastRow();`.
  A better condition would be  `val.length`: the number of elements in the data array.
- "Script should check for today date" but `val[x][0]> curDate` tests for a date greater than today.
  `val[x][0] === curDate` is the correct condition.
- // get the row:  `row = x;`
  Because the data range excluded the header row, and because the loop is zero-based, the row number = `row = x+2`
- **Protection**
  The protection is just plain wrong. Refer [documentation:Class Protection](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection) and the method described in [Apps Script to Build a Data Protection and only allow Spreadsheet Owner to edit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75051884/1330560)

---

```
function blockRanges() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('MY SHEET');
  var lr = ss.getLastRow()
  var lc = ss.getLastColumn()

  // assume row 1 = header
  var dateRange = ss.getRange(2, 1, lr-1, 1);
  var val = dateRange.getDisplayValues()
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: date range = "+dateRange.getA1Notation())

  // get todays Date
  var curDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "dd/M/YYYY").toString()
  // Logger.log("curDate: "+curDate)

  //Loop through date rows looking for a match
  for (var x = 0; x < val.length; x++){
    if(val[x][0] === curDate){
      // get the row; 
      // add one for the header and one for zero-based loop
      row = x+2;
          
      // set protection
      var protectionRange = ss.getRange(row,1,1,lc)
      // Logger.log("DEBUG: the protection range = "+protectionRange.getA1Notation())
      var protection = protectionRange.protect().setDescription(curDate);
      // Ensure the current user is an editor before removing others. Otherwise, if the user's edit
      // permission comes from a group, the script throws an exception upon removing the group.
      // Set the spreadsheet owner as the only editor
      var editors = protection.getEditors();
      for (var i = 0; i < editors.length; i++) {
        protection.removeEditor(editors[i]);
      }
      protection.addEditor("owneraddress@email.com");
    }
  }
}
```