# Apps Script to Build a Data Protection and only allow Spreadsheet Owner to edit

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, permissions

I'm looking to build a script that will create a protected range in the users spreadsheet.  This script will be run from the NON-owner and essentially will lock them from a specific range (it will eventually be tied into an OnEdit).

The end goal is:

When a user edits a specific cell, that row will now longer be able to be edited by anyone except the owner, and the owner alone.

I'm focused on figuring out the permissions right now.

The script I have creates the protected range, but sets the permission rules to "You and the Spreadsheet Owner".

The user should no longer be able to edit.  I tried setting the protection warning to false, but that still allows the user to edit.

The user is triggering the script, but is not the spreadsheet owner.  How could I build a protection range that removes their editing access in a specific range?

```
function RemovePermission() {

var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();

// /

// Define the data range that you want to protect
var range = sheet.getRange("b13:f13");

// Protect the range
var protection = range.protect().setDescription("Protected data range");

// Set the spreadsheet owner as the only editor
var editors = protection.getEditors();
for (var i = 0; i < editors.length; i++) {
protection.removeEditor(editors[i]);
}
protection.addEditor("enter owner email");

// Enable warning when editing
protection.setWarningOnly(true);
}
```

Comment: I think that in your script, when you remove `protection.setWarningOnly(true);` and `RemovePermission()` is installed as the installable OnEdit trigger, when a cell is edited, "b13:f13" of active sheet is protected. In this case, only the owner can edit the range. Is this your expected result? If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: Thanks @Tanaike this is helpful, I removed protection.setWarningOnly(true) --- when I try to run the script from another account (non-owner account), I receive an exception error: "You can't remove yourself as an editor.Details" any thoughts?

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `when I try to run the script from another account (non-owner account), I receive an exception error: "You can't remove yourself as an editor.Details" any thoughts?`, unfortunately, I cannot replicate this. But, I would like to support you. So, can you provide the detailed flow for correctly replicating it? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Answer (score 2):

Modify the code as Tanaike suggested in the comments, and run it through an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable). The code will run under the account of the user who created the trigger.

Do *not* run the function through an `onEdit(e)` [simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers). Simple triggers run under the account of the user at the keyboard.