# Google App Script To Protect Multiple Ranges Based On Current Date

Tags: google-apps-script

In my sheet Column A has date, I want to lock range ColBC, ColE and ColGH till the row in which date in column A is (Today -2). E.g. If today is 22nd March and date in Column A till row number 151 is 20th March or less and from row number 152 21st March and onwards starts, then I want to protect the above three ranges till row no. 151. Further I want to add two editors in the protected range.

I had designed a script based on solution on below two links. The script is running and applying protection and also adding editors in the above three ranges, but protection is applied only for row number 2.

Below are the links from which I had adopted the scripts.

Link 1

This links has give solution to lock multiple range

[Google Sheets Lock Apply Three Different Range Protection With One Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78089179/google-sheets-lock-apply-three-different-range-protection-with-one-script/78089735?noredirect=1#comment137694761_78089735)

Link 2

This link give the solution to lock range based on date.

[Protecting rows depending on specific (today) date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74784221/protecting-rows-depending-on-specific-today-date)

Below is the script which I am using

```
function rangeLock() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); //Change the sheet name if necessary
var end = sourceSheet.getLastRow();
var sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange(1, 2, sourceSheet.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
var editors = ['....@gmail.com', '....@gmail.com'] //Update this array with the     
editors' actual email addresses.
var dateRange = sourceSheet.getRange(2, 1, sourceSheet.getLastRow()-2, 1);
var curDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "dd/M/YYYY");
var val = dateRange.getDisplayValues();
for(var x = 0; x <= end; x++){
if(val[x][0]> curDate){
  row = x;
  break;
}
}

var colBC = sourceSheet.getRange(2, 2, row, 2).getA1Notation(); 
var colE = sourceSheet.getRange(2, 5, row).getA1Notation();
var colGH = sourceSheet.getRange(2, 7, row, 2).getA1Notation();


var rangesToLock = sourceSheet.getRangeList([colBC, colE, colGH]).getRanges(); //returns the  
specific ranges to lock
var currentProtection = sourceSheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE) //Gets 
the sheet's existing protected ranges.

//if there are existing protected ranges, the if statement below will remove it prior to 
protecting the identified ranges.
if(currentProtection.length > 0) currentProtection.forEach(p => p.remove());

rangesToLock.forEach(range => {
protectedRange = range.protect()
protectedRange.removeEditors(protectedRange.getEditors());
protectedRange.addEditors(editors);
if (protectedRange.canDomainEdit()) protectedRange.setDomainEdit(false);
})
}
```

Any help on above will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**I'm use this script:**

```
const dateColumn = 1; // date column
const workSheetName = ['Склад готовой продукции', 'Склад сырья', 'Склад оборудования/хоз. товаров']; // sheets where we will close the range
const protectRangeName = 'закрытые дни'; // range name

/** 
* who will be allowed to edit the protected range 
* list the emails of other employees separated by commas, 
* you may not add yourself.    
*/

const editors = ['zdorovoe.maslo@gmail.com'];

function closeRows() {
  workSheetName.forEach((i) => {
    const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(i);
    const fr = findRow(sheet, dateColumn);
    if (fr > 0) {
      delProtection(sheet, protectRangeName);
      createProtection([sheet.getRange(2, 1, fr - 2, sheet.getMaxColumns() - 1)], [protectRangeName]);
    }
    else {
    }
  });
}

function findRow(sh, column) {
  const data = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  var date = new Date((new Date).getTime() - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24); // date after which we will close the ranges
  return Math.max(...(data.map((g, i) => g[column - 1] && g[column - 1] <= date ? ++i : '')));
}

function delProtection(sheet, name) {
  sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE)
    .forEach((protection) => {
      if (protection.canEdit()) {
        protection.getDescription() == name ? protection.remove() : '';
      }
    })
}

function createProtection(range, names) {
  var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
  range.map((rng, i) => {
    var protection = rng.protect().setDescription(names[i]);
    protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
    protection.canDomainEdit() ? protection.setDomainEdit(false) : '';
    protection.addEditors([me].concat(editors));
  })
}
```

Comment: @ Antonio this is not solving my issue, however, thank you for the reply, this solution suggested by you protects a particular range and that is also not working properly it is showing an error.

Comment: show your logs please,  beacuse this script works for me long time

Comment: it show error of fworkSheetName not defined

Comment: @Essem edit answer, please try again

Comment: @ Antonio thank you for the updated reply, it still shows error, however I managed to get the solution, am sharing it.

Comment: @Essem what error is it giving this time?

Answer (score 0):

Updated script which will perform the desired function.

```
function rangeLock() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); //Change the sheet name if necessary
var end = sourceSheet.getLastRow();
var sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange(1, 2 sourceSheet.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
var editors = ['....@gmail.com', '....@gmail.com']; 
var dateRange = sourceSheet.getRange(2, 1, sourceSheet.getLastRow() - 1,1);
var curDate = new Date();
curDate.setDate(curDate.getDate() - 1);
var val = dateRange.getValues();
var row = 0;

for (var x = 0; x < end - 1; x++) {
var rowDate = new Date(val[x][0]);
if (rowDate < curDate) {
  row = x + 2;
} else {
  break;
}
}

var colBC = sourceSheet.getRange(2, 2, row - 1, 2);
var colE = sourceSheet.getRange(2, 5, row - 1, 1);
var colGH = sourceSheet.getRange(2, 7, row - 1, 2);

var rangesToLock = [colBC, colE, colGH];
var currentProtection = 
sourceSheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE); 

if (currentProtection.length > 0) currentProtection.forEach(p => 
p.remove());

rangesToLock.forEach(range => {
protectedRange = range.protect();
protectedRange.removeEditors(protectedRange.getEditors());
protectedRange.addEditors(editors);
if (protectedRange.canDomainEdit()) protectedRange.setDomainEdit(false);
});
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**